# Android: support FAB not showing a shadow despite borderWidth 0

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-support-design

I have a floating action button that I've added from the support library, however there is no shadow. My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFab"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is the problem here? I've tried setting clipToPadding to false and setting borderWidth to 0 - neither helps.

Edit: added screenshot example:

[image]

Comment: try after remove borderwidth line

Comment: @KhizarHayat thanks, but unfortunately it still looks the same

Comment: What version of the support design library are you using? The `borderwidth="0dp"` bug has been [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067).

Comment: @AlexTownsend I'm using 23.2.0

Comment: What android version/devices is this occurring on?

Comment: @AlexTownsend Nexus 5 running M (6.0.1)

Comment: Post a screenshot or more code if you could.

Comment: @AlexTownsend I added a screenshot

Comment: I can actually see the shadow, decreasing elevation a bit should make it more visible

Comment: There is shadow on the FAB in that screenshot.

Comment: ok, thanks guys. I honestly expected a much thicker darker shadow, but even if I set the elevation to 1dp there's almost nothing there. I guess that's the way it's supposed to work though :/